# Facebook access_token for my application is not working while access_token of graph API is working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

there is a problem with my access token. I have made my own application, and I took the permission from the facebook user, who is me. And also I have given the same permissions to the facebook graph api. However when I can easily get the results using FQL with graph api access token, but I cannot get the result with my own application access token. What is the problem with my access token.

It is not user access token. Maybe this can be problem however also graph api is not also user access token.

Comment: What API call are you making? what is the result with the Graph API Explorer's token and with your own app's token? Is your app out of sandbox mode? Did you verify the permission sets are identical (a call to `/me/permissions` will confirm)

Comment: for example, when I try to find my object Id of an album with my access_token, I get the result
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102
   }
}

But when I try it with graph api access token, I get the result:

   "data": [
      {
         "aid": "2632479622876830347",
         "name": "Untitled Album",
         "object_id": "10151138509846926"
      }
}

I do not what is sandbox mode. Could you explain it to me plz? Also permissions for both of them is same.

Comment: Your first access token is probably not a user access token - it sounds like you're using the app access token - check your [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) code is working correctly, you may not actually have a logged in user

Comment: Actually I want to use my app access token, because I am making a new facebook app. And maybe the error "A user access token is required to request this resource." can be true. Permission that I want, may require user access token. However, also graph api is not a user access token. But it gives the all informations. And the problem I face is how it is possible while graph api access token is working, my app access token is not working.

Comment: is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message you need to use a user access token retrieved via the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow - you cannot use an app access token for this.

You mentioned in the comments you're successfully using an access token from the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) tool - this is also a user access token which the tool retrieves using the client-side oauth flow. This is not the same as using an app access token for your own app.

Comment: I understand. So graph api is using user access token. But I want to fetch the data from stream table using my applications access token. So is not it possible? For example; I can fetch data from stream table using graph api access token, it gives all solutions; however when I want to fetch it using my access token, it gives no error, but data { } just empty. What is the problem of this?